# Compare 2 table and KEEP the ONLY matched data (based on a column) and delete the unmatched

Tags: php, mysqli

I am not sure I am able to describe the situation.

I'm working on a project where I need to compare between 2 tables and then delete all the records that are NOT matched. So the master table should have only the matched data.

What is my problem is, when running the loop, on first iteration, it deletes all the unmatched data except the first reference..

Here is my code..

```
$refTableData2 ="SELECT DISTINCT $oColoum FROM $oTable";
                                                $refTableData2 = mysqli_query($con, $refTableData2);
                                                if (mysqli_num_rows($refTableData2) > 0) {
                                                    while($rerow2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($refTableData2)) {

                                                        $rTableData2= $rerow2[''.$oColoum.''];

                                                        $delete=mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM $mTable WHERE $mColoum != '$rTableData2'");

                                                    }
                                                }
```

Any help would be HIGHLY appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use SQL:

```
DELETE FROM master_table
WHERE match_column NOT IN (
SELECT DISTINCT match_column
FROM other_table);
```